# how to merge and remove conflicts in git when pull from server

Tags: git, openshift, merge-conflict-resolution

We are working as a team of 4 peoples, our project deployed in **openshift**
and we are commit,push and pull with **git repository**.. When some one commit more changes other have to pull it for make a update in our system.. But while pull from the server the **master** get **conflict** and we did't know how to reslove it.

Every time we delete the file and **clone** again from server.. As reference with **stackoverflow**, I solve the problem with **team->merge tool**
 but it does't work in many conditions.

Help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/161813/fix-merge-conflicts-in-git.

Comment: *How* does it not work under *which* conditions?

Comment: @ Wander Nauta Thanks for that link. it will help me more..

Comment: @TimCastelijns if the changes are few using that **merge tool** i will solve the problem. but there is more changes made by me and my colleague also made more changes in same file.. after made the changes in merge tool and click the add to index button. conflicts remains same..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After pull from git repository you get **conflict msg**.. then you should merge the code using merge.. From that you find the **conflict file**.. Then undo the changes, then click **pull again**..
now Do the changes again and commit it.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are all modifying the same files at the same time, that can be difficult.  Usually you will just need to manually merge the files when you do a git pull.  You could also try using rebase.  That should move your changes aside, pull in the remote changes, then reply your changes on top of it.  I have had success with that in the past.